# Plone template complains about UnicodeEncodeError (ascii), but default-zpublisher-encoding is utf-8

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, plone, plone-4.x

I have two Plone instances (in independent Zope instances) which are mostly identical in code, including the search; both are configured to use `utf-8`, both regarding `sys.getdefaultcoding` and `default-zpublisher-encoding`.

Now in one of those sites the search fails for some catalog searches during rendering the search result, probably because of umlauts in the search result:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The HTML is created by call to a template which is `utf-8`-encoded (and identical in both systems), and I have configured both systems to use `utf-8` everywhere (did I miss a place to look?), so why should anything be encoded to or decoded from `ascii`?

Can I force the template to be executed using `utf-8`, or what would the clean solution be (apart from a Plone rewritten for Python 3)?

Thank you!

**Edit:**
Here is a traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 237, in _exec
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 177, in pt_render
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 79, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 240, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  (... deleted 42 lines ...)
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 742, in do_insertStructure_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 218, in evaluateStructure
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: file:/opt/zope/instances/plone2/Products/myproject/skins/myproject_templates/search_view.pt
   - Line 176, Column 16
   - Expression: <PythonExpr search.result()>
   - Names:
      {'container': <PloneSite at /vdz>,
       'context': <PloneSite at /vdz>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7fcdb035f4f0>,
       'here': <PloneSite at /vdz>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': ()},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7fcd688ebfc8>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=https://www.myprojectsite.com:/search_view>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <FSPageTemplate at /vdz/search_view>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <SpecialUser 'Anonymous User'>}
  Module Products.PageTemplates.ZRPythonExpr, line 48, in __call__
   - __traceback_info__: search.result()
  Module PythonExpr, line 1, in <expression>
  Module Products.myproject.browser.myproject_search.browser, line 433, in result
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The executed `result` method of my custom `myproject_search` browser:

```
def result(self):
    """
    Sadly no useful docstring ...
    """
    context = self.context
    res = {'brains': ''}
    try:
        res = {'brains': self.searchQs()}
        string_ = context.restrictedTraverse('kss-search-result')(**res)
    except Unauthorized:
        string_ = "Unauthorized"
    except Exception, e:
        raise e
```

The called `searchQs` method which executes the search makes sure to use a unicode string for the search expression (by a `safe_decode` function which tries unicode (unchanged), `utf-8` and `latin-1`, in this order).

I didn't setup the project in the beginning; perhaps I would have tried to make it without changing the `sys.defaultencoding`.  Now this is required.

Yes, I use `virtualenv`, and it took me some effort to have the default encoding changed in that environment; the project evolved for a while, and it was not `buildout` and `vitualenv` based from the beginning.

Comment: Are you in a position to experiment on a non-production copy of your DB? (On a whim, I'd say ZMI, portal_catalog, Advanced, Clear and rebuild can't hurt.)

Comment: Yes, I can; but I have not been able yet to reproduce the problem in my development copy ... I'll try again in another copy on the same machine.

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? Maybe you have some strange locale encoding customization through old school sitecustomize.py or similar

Comment: sys.getdefaultencoding is normally 'ascii'. Setting it to utf-8 as you have apparently done can help in some cases, but can cause other unexpected problems. It is not recommended. At the very least, it can cause code that works fine on your machine fail on a machine that has ascii as default encoding. Also, can you post a full traceback? That would help in pinpointing the problem.

Comment: Could we see the entire stack trace?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to answer; I added the traceback and some code.